# Downloading HTML links from an online query search

Tags: download, wget, password-encryption, blast

I have posted this question at SE Bioinformatics. But I think this is is ultimately a programming problem.

I have just started using this website BlastKOALA KEGG for searching for (aminoacid) sequences similarities.

This is the website: https://www.kegg.jp/blastkoala/

When you get results, there are links for downloading. However these links will not download all detailed query search results, but just download the HTML screen already showing. To get these results I need to manually click on each query result on the page, which becomes impracticable with >500 entries. Thus I think need is a tool to download all linked contents from a webpage.

I have attempted 'wget' however with no success. Example code below:

```
wget -r -l3 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -erobots=off https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/blastkoala_result?id=7345faab3969a3ef10a4a7542ba749386068138f&passwd=NKfm46&type=blastkoala
```

It says 'Requested Job Not Found', even if I change several parameters.

Please, did anyone every encounter such a problem? Thanks in advance.

A working link (I think it should remain active for a week.):

https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/blastkoala_result?id=7345faab3969a3ef10a4a7542ba749386068138f&passwd=NKfm46&type=blastkoala

Comment: The posted link does not work. Can you edit the question with a working link?

Comment: You can check Selenium. https://www.seleniumhq.org/. I have used it in past to download files where other methods were more time-consuming. Also, your link is not working and I see a password queryParameter. I hope you are aware of the security issues it might lead to.

Comment: Sorry, the link is only valid for a few days after the query was made. I'd have to do another search and thus renew the link. Meantime I think I found a working solution